# how to get raise exception from model to controller level in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

how to get nonactive record model raise exception in the controller action in rails

Example

```
  def template_type_test(revision)
    if revision == PHOTO_REV
      template_type = :photo_template
    elsif revision == TEXT_REV
      template_type = :text_template
    else
      raise 'Unexpected revision in template.  Use the template provided by Right-Photo.'
    end
  end
```

how to get this raise exception in controller action ?

Please share your ideas?

Comment: is doing it already. Could you explain what do you mean?

Comment: When you will call this method on an object, it will throw an exception if it goes in else condition.
    @your_object.template_type_test(revision_you_want_to_pass)